# Does JSON spit array data into smaller chunks for presentation purposes?

Tags: arrays, json

I am working with an api that returns JSON data. The data returned has me a bit confused.

It looks like so:

```
{
    "response":151 items
        [0 - 100]
        [100 - 151]
}
```

I can see that it is saying that 151 items have been returned as `response`. So it means that `response` is one array. Is this correct? Is the presentation of two arrays only for presentation purposes or does it mean `response` is an array of arrays?

Comment: No, what you're seeing isn't JSON, it's just the way some devtools consoles show very large arrays -- and yes, it's to make it easier to access what's in the array from the devtools console. The actual data in the array is not grouped like that.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. Now I understand.